# Adding URL Query parameters to WP_Query

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I am implementing a product filter for my WooCommerce store. I want to filter the product base on some attributes, such as color, which can be retrieve from the URL query parameters. For example, if the path is `/product-category/clothing/?filter_color=16`, then only product with color ID = 16 would be shown.

Right now this feature seems to be available when I added the widget from `YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter` Plugin. However, I do not want to use this plugin because it is not consistent with other features and would like to implement my own. But I couldn't find how YITH achieve this.

I want to make this work for both the main Loop and my custom Loops.
By main loop I am referring to this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

And my custom loops:

```
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 12,
                    'product_cat' => $category->slug,
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                    );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $loop->have_posts() ) { ...
```

Comment: Do you have any clue what is WP's parameter for color of a product? In other words, how is the color of a product defined or retrieved in WooCommerce/WP?

Comment: Try using the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook.

Comment: @Sina I am able to access the color like this `get_the_terms($product->ID,'pa_color')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the query, retrieve the value of the color, check if they match and if so then display the product. Have a look at:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['filter_color']) //check if the filter color is set
    {
        $color=$_GET['filter_color']; 
        $productColor = get_the_terms($product->ID,'pa_color');

        if ($color == $productColor) //if the filter color matches with the color of the prodct
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); //then show the product
    }

    ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Same approach applies for your custom loops.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but would it be more efficient to do the filtering at the query level?

Comment: No worries. It would not make much of a difference I reckon.Though I would suggest you to put on an `else`, if in case there are no color filtering or queries passed at all.

Comment: Awesome, enjoy coding :)